# OnCollisionEnter not detecting collisions (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a problem where everytime I run the unity game the collision detection does not work, I was going to add a fridge to my cooking game that you could open and it would bring up a UI containing all of the items inside the fridge, here is the code for the fridge

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenFridge : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject fridgeUI;
    public GameObject player;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Capsule")
        {
            fridgeUI.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

For those that were wondering, I am using a capsule for the player and there is a rigid body on the fridge. If you have anyway to fix this, please leave it in the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that you're adding your script to the GameObject which has the Rigidbody and Collider attached to?  I've just had an issue where it wasn't working for me and it turned that I'd put the script on a parent GameObject and not the GameObject which had the Rigidbody and Collider on it

Answer (score 2):

One of the rigid bodies has to be [non-kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html), and both need to have a collider attached.

If GameObjects are on different [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), you also need to make sure collision between them is enabled.

Also, if you don't really want a physical collision, you could also think about using a [trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) instead.

Comment: I'll try doing that later.

Comment: I tried doing all three of the things you suggested me to do and they did not work, I am pretty sure that most of them didn't work because I have already done them (Non-Kinematic rigidbodys and layers fix). I did the trigger collision and that also did not work. Just saying this so that people don't give me the same fix later, Thanks.